# How can I make sure that I am pointing to the correct DB when updating in EF?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have an MVC site comprised of the following projects:

WebPortal

WebPortal.DataAccess

I am using EF6 to an Oracle 11g DB.

Inside each of the projects in the respective app/web config files are 2 EF settings.

```
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <dataSource alias="MyTNS" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxx)))" />
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ReportModel.csdl|res://*/ReportModel.ssdl|res://*/ReportModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=MyTNS;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXXX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</connectionStrings>
```

Also there is MyTNS setting in my Oracle Tools for Visual Studio path.

I have 2 DB's.

QA 

PROD

QA has a table with 3 fields that don't exist in PROD.

I switched every setting that I can find in my projects to point to PROD.

However when I remove the table from my model and re-add the table I see the 3 new fields.  
So this tells me that EF is not looking in the PROD database.

How can I make sure that I am pointing to the correct DB when updating in EF?

EDIT:  I am database first.

Comment: How about checking the actual connection string, like `new MyEntities().Database.Connection.ConnectionString`?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the .edmx file and check on the property panel (F4), under Connection String you can see what db is pointing to, you can change it on your web/app .config.

Comment: It shows username, password and data source.  Doesn't show db.